# PL SQL - Deleting rows from table based on the ID in a collection

Tags: sql, plsql, collections

I have an issue I'm hoping someone could assist me with.
My goal is to insert several rows based on some conditions on different tables, and after that delete those rows from the original tables.

So far I have succeeded in inserting, but for deleting I'm having some difficulties. Now I'm trying to store the ID's of the rows to be inserted in some collection, so I can delete the rows with those ID's on the DELETE operation.

Code example:

...

```
TYPE array_type IS VARRAY(100000) OF INTEGER;
array_SYSID array_type;
total_ids INTEGER;

    BEGIN
    SELECT a1.SYS_ID BULK COLLECT INTO array_SYSID FROM NOCCIA_TICKET_JOURNEY_CONTROL a1 WHERE (((CAST(a1.SYS_CREATED_ON as DATE) < CAST(archive_date as DATE) AND INSTR(LISTOFFINALSTATES, a1.U_JOURNEY_STATUS) > 0 )) AND a1.SYS_ID NOT IN (SELECT b1.U_TICKET_JOURNEY_SYSID FROM NOCCIA_AUTOMATION_CONTROL b1 WHERE b1.U_STATUS LIKE '%In Automation'));
    total_ids := array_SYSID.count;
    FOR i in 1 .. total_ids LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line(array_SYSID(i));
    END LOOP;

    DELETE FROM NOCCIA_TICKET_JOURNEY_CONTROL
    WHERE SYS_ID IN array_SYSID;
```

The error I'm getting is : "local collection types not allowed in SQL statements". I've tried reading into this error but still couldn't understand what the best solution would be to the issue.

Thanks,
Best regards.

Comment: Edited the code to include declarations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [`FORALL`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/lnpls/FORALL-statement.html#GUID-C45B8241-F9DF-4C93-8577-C840A25963DB):

```
...
forall i in array_SYSID.first .. array_SYSID.last     
    DELETE FROM NOCCIA_TICKET_JOURNEY_CONTROL
    WHERE SYS_ID= array_SYSID(i);
...
```

Comment: +1 There is the possibility to use the collection in a sub-select, but that can easily get very slow indeed. forall is exactly for this use-case

Answer (score 0):

You have almost got it! Just several places to point out:
1) declare the type globally, not in the inner anonymous block, like :

```
create or replace type array_type is varry(100000) of integer;
```

2) the final code is:

```
declare

  array_SYSID array_type;
  total_ids INTEGER;

BEGIN

  SELECT 
    a1.SYS_ID 
  BULK COLLECT INTO 
    array_SYSID 
  FROM 
    NOCCIA_TICKET_JOURNEY_CONTROL a1 
  WHERE(((
    CAST(a1.SYS_CREATED_ON as DATE) < CAST(archive_date as DATE) AND 
    INSTR(LISTOFFINALSTATES, a1.U_JOURNEY_STATUS) > 0 )) AND 
    a1.SYS_ID NOT IN(
      SELECT 
        b1.U_TICKET_JOURNEY_SYSID 
      FROM 
        NOCCIA_AUTOMATION_CONTROL b1 
      WHERE 
        b1.U_STATUS LIKE '%In Automation'));

  total_ids := array_SYSID.count;

  FOR i in 1 .. total_ids LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line(array_SYSID(i));
  END LOOP;

  DELETE FROM NOCCIA_TICKET_JOURNEY_CONTROL
  WHERE SYS_ID IN(
    select
      *
    from
      table(array_SYSID);

end;
```